# Fast writing in a textBox with selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python, html, windows, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Python (Chorme driver) to write something in a text box but there are a lot of textboxes and I need it to fill them faster. I use a sequences of

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='string required' and @id='order_billing_name']").send_keys("test.com")
```

commands but to write 10-11 these takes a lot of time. Is there a way to fast it up?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `fill them faster`? What is your exact _usecase_?

Comment: because after a period of  12 secon the page will reload , so i need to fill the textbox faster

Comment: try finding all the elements at once based on just the class: elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='string required']").  Then loop: for e in elements: sendkeys...

Comment: How many fields do you want to fill up in 12 seconds? Is it manually possible? What does the _usecase_ says about it?

Comment: first thing is to find out what's taking long time: `find_element_by_xpath` or `send_keys`. Different problems. Also since your xpath includes ID, there's really no need for other atributes, so your xpath could be `"//input[@id='order_billing_name']"`. But then if it's always ID, you could use `find_element_by_id` instead, which is faster. Although still, figure out first what takes time: finding or typing

Comment: as per my experience `Css selector` is the fastest locator of all. Also, you can use `List<WebElement>` to locate all elements and send text which is faster than locating element individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set values using javascript:

```
orderBillingName = driver.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", orderBillingName, "mytext")
```

You can set all directly with javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#order_billing_name').value='mytext';"\
                   "document.querySelector('.order_number_class').value='12323';"\
                   "document.querySelector('input#anotherinputid').value='anything';")
```

Example for a lot fields:

```
fields = {
    "input#order_billing_name": "some text", 
    ".order_number_class"     : "some text", 
    "css selector"            : "some text", 
    "css selector"            : "some text",
    "css selector"            : "some text"
    }

js = ""
for selector, value in fields.items():
    js = js + "document.querySelector('" + selector + "').value='"+ value +"';"

driver.execute_script(js)
```

Comment: the problem is that doing river.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name") it can't find the textbox for this reason i did that with xpath

Comment: @Marià css selector `input#order_billing_name` or `input[id='order_billing_name']` should work

Comment: it seems to work but if i want to "document.querySelector('.order_number_class').value='12323';" but inste 12323 i want ssend a python variable ?

Comment: @Marià of cause you can send variable. For example check how you can handle your all fields in my answer update.

Comment: thk so much for your answers. But if for instance i want to send another javascript code like for instance an alert ?

Comment: @Marià I didn't understand what "javascript code like for instance an alert" mean. With `execute_script`you can send any javascript code

Comment: i'm trying to do driver.execute_script("input[name="commit"]').click()") but it gives me error

Comment: `driver.execute_script("document. querySelector('input[name=\"commit\"]').click();")`   or    `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='commit']"))`