# Selenium clearing and typing in text into textarea text box [Python]

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to do some scraping. I used the following code to input the text into a `textarea` text box:

```
def clear_and_send_key_then_wait(element, key, sleep_time = 1):
# For some reason this does not work
#     element.clear() 

# This works
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE);

# Input text
    element.send_keys(key)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

target_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/textarea""")
clear_and_send_key_then_wait(target_textbox, 'z'*100000)
```

**Q1: Why doesn't `element.clear()` remove the existing text in the textbox?**

Since a lot of texts have to be typed into the text box, the above method is too slow. Instead, I use the first Javascript method `execute_script` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336190/fast-writing-in-a-textbox-with-selenium-and-python).

However, simply doing the following does not fill the text box.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", 
                      target_textbox, "z"*100000)
```

The text only appears after another `send_key` command follows immediately after the `execute_script` line:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", 
                      target_textbox, "z"*100000)
target_textbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**Q2: Why is the subsequent `target_textbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` required? It seems like in the link, the author does not need to send Enter key. Is it a different type of text box? If so, what are the different types of text boxes and do they all have different behaviors?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the back end code? There are many different ways to create a text box for your web page see the following 3 links.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D,
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: Thanks Jortega! No I don't. Can we tell from the page source?

Comment: You could get a Chrome plugin to tell you f it uses angular or react. Google "react plugin chrome" or "angular plugin chrome". But honestly that will not really help with answering the question of why they behave differently.  Depending on what the text box is used for it could purposefully be designed to behave differently.

Comment: @DebanjanB Feel free to answer any sub-part of the question!

Comment: Which browser and version are you using? Which web driver and driver version are you using?

Comment: Chrome: Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit), Python: 3.7.4, Selenium: 3.141.0. I use webdriver from Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium doesn't fire any keyboard or mouse events on clear. Same happens when you set value using JavaScript. Probably the website waits for the keys event to proceed some work for the textarea's value and trigger for that is `send_keys` with any key.

You can try the code below, `\ue007` is Enter key:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", target_textbox, "z"*100000 + "\ue007")
```