# How to set text in textarea quickly using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

This code work but `sendKeys` send all char one by one and is it very very long time (40s).

```
String value = "...very long text...";
WebElement element = ...
element.sendKeys(value);
```

How to set text in textarea quickly using Java and Selenium? either with an element of Selenium or by modifying the speed or the characters are sent one by one temorary.

**Please no solution with javascript execution.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast writing in a textBox with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336190/fast-writing-in-a-textbox-with-selenium-and-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740310/selenium-clearing-and-typing-in-text-into-textarea-text-box-python/59742061#59742061)

Comment: @Sers, You do not read `Please no solution with javascript execution.` ?

Comment: There's no any configuration you can change to speed up send keys. Why not using JS, are there any restriction and what they are?

Comment: That is my question. I will not change my question to stick with your answer, it is not my need.

Comment: No one ask you to change your question. Good luck

Comment: yes a little anyway, it is well noted in the question `Please no solution with javascript execution.`

Comment: There're two workarounds to do it. One is JavaScript.

Comment: the workaround is not great. I have to delete the last character and sendKeys with the last character. I'm going to do with that for the moment because there doesn't seem to be a solution in Selenium yet.

Comment: not Selenium, but you could use Robot to fill the clipboard and then paste it.

Comment: @pcalkins, have you a sample?

Comment: Fill clipboard using plain old Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html  Then use Robot to send keys, Ctrl-V... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631933/how-would-i-make-a-paste-from-java-using-the-system-clipboard

Comment: come to think of it, you may be able to just use WebDriver to send Ctrl-V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**/!\ Caution, is it a workaround only.**

```
String value = "...very long text...";
WebElement element = ...
String javascript = "arguments[0].value=arguments[1];";
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript(javascript, element, value.substring(0, value.length() - 1));
element.sendKeys(value.substring(value.length() - 1));
```

**/!\ 2nd workaround (not work on remote):**

```
String value = "...very long text..."; 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(value), null);
WebElement element = ... 
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL , "v");
```

Comment: You mentioned in your question "no answers with Javascript execution" but you just posted an answer to your own question using JSE. Should this be an edit to your question instead?

Comment: @Christine, I note `Caution, is it a workaround only.`, my question is still valid if you have a solution.

Comment: @sgrillon I tried multiple Javascript solutions, none worked. This WORKED like a CHARM. Thanks for your 'Caution, is it a workaround only' solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to use the clipboard for this:

```
    String value = "...very long text...";      
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable transferable = new StringSelection(value);
    clipboard.setContents(transferable, null);  
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ec_Timeout);     
    WebElement element  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("name_of_input_element")));
    String vKey = "v";

            try
            {
        element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL , vKey);    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sendKeys` method is the only pure Java way to enter text into a text field using Selenium. Unfortunately all other ways require JavaScript, which is something you do not want to do.

Your only other alternative is to contribute to the [Selenium project on GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) by [submitting a pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pulls) with the desired behavior, and convince the World Wide Web Consortium to include this new method (`sendKeysQuickly`?) in the official WebDriver spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/ — not a small task indeed!

Comment: done. thank you.   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7937

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value directly using js script:

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('textareaId').setAttribute('value', 'yourText')");
```

Comment: You do not read `Please no solution with javascript execution.` ?

Comment: @sgrillon sendkeys was build to work sequential, the only way to make it "fast" is with js, simply because selenium have no access to the dom directly, actually, all the dom manipulations are made through js

Comment: my question is how to reduce the time between each send key (by configuration)? No by javascript.

Comment: I find my elements via an xpath, I don't necessarily have the id