# Insert text inside 'div' with Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Do you have any more ideas about inserting text into div tag with selenium? Below are my examples.
I want to insert some long string between div tags

THIS EXAMPLE WORKED, but with very long string it lasts forever.

```
text_area.clear()
text_area.send_key(very_long_string)
```

THIS EXAMPLE DOES NOT WORK:

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='divtextarea1']").text
#example above ^ doesnt work without .text/.value either
driver.execute_script("arguments[0] = arguments[1]", text_area, my_text)
'''
```

Comment: you'll want to send keys to the input tag, not the div.  This will "type" the characters.  You can also paste them in if it takes too long.  See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752886/how-to-set-text-in-textarea-quickly-using-java-and-selenium/59779306#59779306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to copy string and paste it as text in web.
Example below copy string value from code into clipboard, like with ctrl+c

```
string_variable = "test"
os.system('echo %s| clip' % string_variable) #copy string, like ctrl+c
text_area.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")      #paste string, like ctrl+v
```

But I was looking for something else, because 'echo' does not work with very long string.
In my task i had to paste whole .xml file value into text area and i did it like below.

```
xmlfile = "C:\\Users\\myfile.xml"
os.system('type "%s" | clip' % xmlfile)      #copy whole file value(string), like ctrl+c
text_area.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")      #paste string, like ctrl+v
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be corrected to set the "value" of the text fields from the javascript layer.

```
text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='divtextarea1']")
# Need to make sure the "value" attribute is set from the JS command
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", text_area, my_text)
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp

Comment: idk why, but with div "arguments[0].value" return null. I can see div value with "arguments[0].text", but execute_script does not work. I found out an solution for me, ill leave it in comment below. Thanks for your advices :)