# The data I wrote with send.key in Selenium writes very slowly, how can I speed up with internet explorer?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

The data I wrote with send.key in Selenium writes very slowly, how can I speed up?

```
loginuser = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/input[6]")))
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
loginuser.send_keys("xxxx")
```

Comment: You can use clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752886/how-to-set-text-in-textarea-quickly-using-java-and-selenium/59779306#59779306

Comment: just asking - why you doing the `implicitly_wait` after the `wait.until` ??